# Houses keep catching fire, why?

Tags: anno-1602

I'm very unsure why... but my houses on my island keep catching fire.

I've got the fire department all over so the fire never spreads beyond 3 houses if I'm unlucky, but I just don't get why they keep popping up in the first place.

Is it because of the density maybe? I can't find anything on the internet about this (I probably didn't search properly though somehow).

[image: Main island]

Sorry for the low image quality, Anno 1602 doesn't take kind to Alt + Tab and taking a screenshot otherwise was impossible.

Answer (score 2):

There is always a chance that houses will catch on fire. However chance increases when there is stagnation in development.

If you reach Merchants/Aristocrats fires will become very rare.

Good strategy would be not to spam a lot of wooden houses and refuse them to use tools for upgrade, but rather buy tools from merchants and give people hope to become higher class.

Less houses - less chance of fire. Better developed houses - less chance of fire.

And also don't fight aborigines, or else they will curse you and fires/volcanoes/diseases/droughts will happen more often.

Comment: Citizens (translated freely, meaning the state above settlers) _never_ catch on fire on their own (see http://1602.annowiki.de/index.php?title=Feuerwehr, german only, unfortunately, but the page has a lot of expertise afaik).

Answer (score 1):

First off all you can just press print abf and paste it into paint later.

As far as i know houses have a random chance to ignite simulating a cooking fire that spreads or somthing like that.

Comment: My island must consist of terrible cooks then... A house sets fire about once per 3-5 minutes.